# Union tables instead of intersect

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the follow structure

```
user
id | name
----------
1  | Foo
2  | Bar

profile
id | name      | user_id
--------------------------
1  | Profile 1 | 1
2  | Profile 2 | 2

profile_access
id | user_id | profile_id
--------------------------
1  | 2       | 1
```

Expect the follow result from a query

```
id | name      | user_id
-----------------------------------
1  | Profile 1 | 1
2  | Profile 2 | 2
1  | Profile 1 | 2
```

But I do't know how to "merge" these tables. I tried:

```
SELECT profile.*
FROM profile profile
LEFT JOIN profile_access AS profile_access
ON (
   profile_access.profile_id = profile.id
)
```

Which returns

```
id | name      | user_id
-----------------------------------
1  | Profile 1 | 1
2  | Profile 2 | 2
```

And

```
SELECT profile.*
FROM profile profile
RIGHT JOIN profile_access AS profile_access
ON (
   profile_access.profile_id = profile.id
)
```

Which results

```
id | name      | user_id
-----------------------------------
2  | Profile 1 | 2
```

What is the correct way to do this query? Am I using joins wrong or expecting a impossible result with these tables?

**EDIT:**
Expected result should be:

```
id | name      | user_id
-----------------------------------
1  | Profile 1 | 1
2  | Profile 2 | 2
1  | Profile 1 | 2
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your expected output? Double check the ids

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what the exact logic you want is, but the following returns the results in the question:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.user_id
from profile p
union all
select p.id, p.name, pa.user_id
from profile p join
     profile_access pa
     on pa.profile_id = p.id;
```

EDIT:

This returns:

```
id | name      | user_id
-----------------------------------
1  | Profile 1 | 1
2  | Profile 2 | 2
1  | Profile 1 | 2
```

Note that the last row has a `1` for the id instead of a `2` (as in the original expected answer).  This is sensible to me, because `id = 1` is only tied to profile name = `'Profile 1'` in the table.  But, to get the actual output:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.user_id
from profile p
union all
select pa.profile_id, p.name, pa.user_id
from profile p join
     profile_access pa
     on pa.user_id = p.user_id;
```

The reason I went with the first solution is because the sample queries all join `profile` and `profile_access` on the `profile_id` field and not on the `user_id` field.

Comment: Here's the SQLFiddle, since I was working on the same thing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18ea8/3

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. You can see the results do not match the expected output. I believe this is an error in the question, though

Comment: And you your answer ;D